# Can forests have circuits?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, definition

One condition for a graph to be a forest is to not have loops. However, I couldn't understand if it can't have circuits either. So my question, if the circuit isn't a loop, can it have a circuit and still be a tree?

Comment: What's the difference between a circuit and a cycle (i.e., a closed path)?

Comment: A circuit can repeat vertices, but not the cycle

Comment: @DuarteArribas Well if you have a tree with adjacent vertices $u$, $v$ and $w$ in your forest, would $u\to v \to w \to v \to u$ be a circuit?

Comment: @Luke: No, because while a circuit may repeat vertices, it may not repeat edges.

Comment: well, it depends on the edges

Answer (score 2):

No, a forest cannot have a circuit, because a circuit cannot repeat any edge. As a result, any graph that contains a circuit also contains a cycle.

**Added:** Either the circuit is a cycle, or it has more than one vertex that repeats. Among all repetitions, take the shortest; say that it’s from vertex $v$ back to vertex $v$. The part of the circuit from $v$ back to $v$ is then a cycle: the choice of $v$ ensures that $v$ is the only vertex repeated in that segment.

Comment: That is not true, it's possible to have a circuit that repeats vertices, but not edges, hence having a circuit does not mean it contains a cycle. The inverse is true though

Comment: @DuarteArribas: If a graph has a circuit that repeats vertices, it also has a cycle. Note that I did **not** say that the circuit **is** a cycle.

Comment: But a cycle cannot repeat vertices, so a circuit that repeats vertices is not a cycle.

Comment: @DuarteArribas: I did not say that it was. One more time: if a graph contains a circuit, it contains a cycle. The circuit need not be a cycle, but if it is not one, the graph has a smaller cycle.

Comment: @DuarteArribas: I’ve added some further explanation to the answer.